# In Django, my staticfiles are way to large (over 500K files), how can I divide the load?

Tags: python, django

My current situation is that I have a tiny portion of my statifiles
which will be updated very frequently, such as website .js and .css, images, etc.

A majority of these staticfiles however, are data elements, which will only be updated once every month or so. (These files are in the staticfiles directories for good reason, let's assume that they must be there)

The command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now effectively takes 10-30 minutes to run, so when i need to update my .js or .css files, i'm still waiting huge lengths for all those data elements to process.

Is there someway I can collectstatic dynamically only on certain folders??

Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have to run `collectsstatic` to upgrade the software in production, and it takes two minutes (during which production must be down or in read-only mode), often when there are no changes in static files (but I can't possibly know that). The `--link` parameter sometimes helps a little (although not in my case).

Comment: You couls always just remove them from your application and manage / deploy them separately. (`rsync` them to production maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [exclude files and folders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic):

> --ignore
>
> Ignore files or directories matching this glob-style pattern. Use multiple times to ignore more.